# Bundle using Mux

Tags: chisel, firrtl

I want to use Mux to choose bundle
enter code here
class ComIO extends Bunlde {
val in = Input(UInt(32.W)
val in = Input(UInt(32.W)
}

```
class EntIO extends Bundle {
  val com = new ComIO
}
class Ent extends Module {
  val io = IO(new EntIO)
  ...
}
class DemoIO extends Bundle {
  val com1 = new ComIO
  val com2 = new ComIO
  val en = Input(Bool())
}

class Demo extends Module {
  val io = IO(new DemoIO)
  val ent = Module(new Ent)

  ent.io <> Mux(io.en,io.com1,io.com2)
}

enter code here
```

The Error is flowing

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6bXss.png)

Answer (score 0):

Muxes are unidirectional, you can't use them for bidirectional things. Try using a `when`:

```scala
class Demo extends Module {
  val io = IO(new DemoIO)
  val ent = Module(new Ent)

  when (io.en) {
    ent.io <> io.com1
  } .otherwise {
    ent.io <> io.com2
  }
}
```